# Can't call model class's method from Component.html in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am a beginner in angular js 2. Currently,

I have defined a component to display list members. From template the HTML, I want to call a `getAvatar()` method of a member. But, I got following error:

[Error] ERROR – TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.getAvatar is not a function. (In '_v.context.$implicit.getAvatar()', '_v.context.$implicit.getAvatar' is undefined)
TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.getAvatar is not a function. (In '_v.context.$implicit.getAvatar()', '_v.context.$implicit.getAvatar' is undefined)
    error
    View_MyChatsListComponent_2 (MyChatsListComponent.ngfactory.js:20)
    logError (vendor.bundle.js:79083)
    (anonymous function)
    handleError (vendor.bundle.js:66715)
    tick (vendor.bundle.js:70507)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:70378:111)
    onInvoke (vendor.bundle.js:69568)
    run (polyfills.bundle.js:2556)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:70378:86)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:69270)
    __tryOrUnsub (vendor.bundle.js:23417)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:23364)
    _next (vendor.bundle.js:23304)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:23268)
    next (vendor.bundle.js:23012)
    emit (vendor.bundle.js:69256)
    checkStable (vendor.bundle.js:69533)
    onLeave (vendor.bundle.js:69609)
    onInvokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:69562)
    runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2606)
    invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:2901)
    (anonymous function) (polyfills.bundle.js:4669)

**Model Class:**

```
import { GlobalConst } from './global';

export class Member {
  id: number;

  getAvatar(): string {
    return GlobalConst.BASE_API_URL + "/users/" + this.id + "/avatar?w=60&amp;h=60";
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Member } from './member';
import { MemberService } from './member.service';
import { GlobalConst, GlobalVar } from './global';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-members-list',
    templateUrl: './my-members-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './my-members-list.component.css' ]
})

export class MyMembersListComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Chat API';
  members: Member[];

  constructor(
    private memberService: MemberService,
    private router: Router
  ){};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.memberService.getMembers()
        .then( members => {
            this.members = members;
        });
  }

  getAvatar(member: Member): string {
    return GlobalConst.BASE_API_URL + "/users/" + member.id + "/avatar?w=60&amp;h=60";
  }
}
```

**Service For Members**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';


import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Member } from './member';
import { GlobalConst, GlobalVar } from './global';


@Injectable()

    export class ChannelService {

        private memberUrl: string = "<it is a private url>"

        constructor(private http: Http, localStorage: LocalStorageService) {};  

        getMembers(): Promise<Member[]> {
            return this.http.get( this.memberUrl, {headers: GlobalVar.httpHeader})
                   .toPromise()
                   .then( response => {
                    return response.json() as Member[];
                   })
                   .catch( this.errorHandler );
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<li class="mix active" style="display: block;" *ngFor="let member of members">
  <div class="media">

    <div class="media-left">
        <span>
          <img src="{{member.getAvatar()}}" class="avatar">
        </span>
        <span class="status offline"></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</li>
```

If write the `getAvatar()` method in component and pass the member as a parameter, then it works smoothly. But, in the later case, I have to write this `getAvatar()` in all the component where I want to display the member's image.

Please suggest if you have any other solution for reusability.

Comment: Can you show how your component gets access to `members`?

Comment: @FrankModica sure, let me update the question

Comment: You also have a syntax error. `this..id` should be `this.id`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I rectified that.

Comment: Seems your `members` variable is just array of objects not array of `Member` classes

Comment: @yurzui then, what would be the correct syntax.

Comment: You should show your implementation of the `memberService.getMembers()` method

Comment: `this.members = members.map(x => Object.assign(new Member(), x));`

Comment: @PierreDuc I am going to update .

Comment: @yurzui thanks, let me try.

Comment: Thanks, @yurzui, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return response.json() as Member[]` does not magically create a member array. like yurzui said in his comment, you need to initiate the `Member` instances, change your method to:

```
this.http.get( this.memberUrl, {headers: GlobalVar.httpHeader})
         .map(response => response.json)
         .map(x => Object.assign(new Member(), x))
         .toPromise()
         .catch(this.errorHandler);
```

The casting in TypeScript just hints the compiler, it doesn't actually do anything in the compiled JavaScript

Comment: Thanks, @PierreDuc.

Answer (score 0):

Create one service which will provide you getAvatar() method. Inject that service wherever you want to access the getAvatar() method. Pass id to this method. as you have done which you have explained in later part of question. Only move that method to service so that it is accessible across the components.